# How do I use an auxilliary file for my own commands?

Tags: macros, labels

I would like to extend the `\label` and `\ref` commands to provide me not only with the number of the section but also some sort of heading.

What I have in mind is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatother
\let\oldlabel\label
\def\Ref#1{see~\ref{#1}~(\csname l@#1\endcsname)}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\label}{m o}%
{
\oldlabel{#1}
\IfValueTF{#2}%
    {\expandafter\gdef\csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}}
    {}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \section{Intro}\label{intro}[Introduction]
    Some text referencing \Ref{intro} or \Ref{outro}
    \section{Outro}\label{outro}[Outro]
    blah...
\end{document}
```

However, if I use \Ref with a forward reference I get an error because `\l@outro` is not yet defined. I would like to fix that by writing these `\gdef`s into an aux file and including at the begin of the document at the second latex run.

Therefore, my questions are:
1) How can I properly write `\gdef`s into an aux file, say `\jobname`.ref ?
2) How can I safely read the aux file? (It might not yet exist...)

The problem with undefined commands isn't a problem since `\@ifundefined` can be used. But let's assume all labels specify the optional argument so far.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am sorry, actually I don't get an error but \csname...\endcsname just results in an empty text.

Comment: I sort of figured it out... I am going to post the answer as soon as possible but not tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use the newfile package for my purposes.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xparse,ifthen}
    \usepackage{newfile,hyperref}
    \makeatother
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \newoutputstream{refs}
        \let\oldlabel\label
        \let\oldsect\section
        \DeclareDocumentCommand{\label}{m o}%
        {
        \oldlabel{#1}
        \IfValueTF{#2}%
                {%
                \addtostream{refs}{\protect\DeclareDocumentCommand{\string\l@#1}{}{#2}}
                }
                {}
        }
        \def\Ref#1{see~\ref{#1}~(\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\undefined{??}\else{\csname l@#1\endcsname}\fi)}
        \def\section#1\label#2{\oldsect{#1}\label{#2}[#1]}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
            \IfFileExists{\jobname.ref}{\input{\jobname.ref}}{}
            \openoutputfile{\jobname.ref}{refs}
            \addtostream{refs}{\protect\makeatletter}

            \section{Intro}\label{intro}
            Some text referencing \Ref{intro} or \Ref{outro}
            \section{Outro}\label{outro}
            blah... see \pageref{intro} or \autoref{intro}

            \addtostream{refs}{\protect\makeatother}
            \closeoutputstream{refs}
    \end{document}
```

In the end, I redefined the commands `\section#1\label#2` to store the section title `#1` into `\l@#2` for later use by `\Ref`. Of course, in the end I need to redefine `\chapter`, `\subsection` etc. too.

If you have any further improvements or found some errors please let me know.

Comment: Well, the reason why I redefined `\section#1\label#2` is that TeXnicCenter recognized these two commands for the navigation panel and the code completion. I did not want to define new commands which are not recognized by TeXnicCenter OR which would be redundant by defining arguments twice such as `\section{A}\label{sec:A}\sect{sec:A}{A}`.